# BAT file to add file to multiple IP's

Tags: loops, batch-file, ip

This is my `.bat` file:

```
@cls
echo on

FOR /F "delims=" %IP3% IN (servers.txt) DO (    
NET USE * /D /Y 
NET USE z: \\10.8.%IP3%.201\e$\NewPOS61\help /user:Administrator A
copy D:\NewPOS61\help\*.jpg z:\ /Y 
copy D:\NewPOS61\help\*.html z:\ /Y 

NET USE * /D /Y 
NET USE z: \\10.8.%IP3%.202\e$\NewPOS61\help /user:Administrator A
copy D:\NewPOS61\help\*.jpg z:\ /Y 
copy D:\NewPOS61\help\*.html z:\ /Y 

NET USE * /D /Y 
NET USE z: \\10.8.%IP3%.217\e$\NewPOS61\help /user:Administrator A
copy D:\NewPOS61\help\*.jpg z:\ /Y 
copy D:\NewPOS61\help\*.html z:\ /Y 

NET USE * /D /Y 
NET USE z: \\10.8.%IP3%.219\e$\NewPOS61\help /user:Administrator A
copy D:\NewPOS61\help\*.jpg z:\ /Y 
copy D:\NewPOS61\help\*.html z:\ /Y 

NET USE * /D /Y 
NET USE z: \\10.8.%IP3%.220\e$\NewPOS61\help /user:Administrator A 
copy D:\NewPOS61\help\*.jpg z:\ /Y 
copy D:\NewPOS61\help\*.html z:\ /Y
```

This is `servers.txt`:

```
200
201
```

I'm trying to copy the files into different drives at multiple IP addresses from `servers.txt`.

Comment: That's not a valid variable for a `for` loop. It _must_ be a single character (A through Z or #).

Comment: @Jelico if you read the help for the command you are using before you ask a question you can probably solve the problem yourself.  Straight from the FOR command HELP: **FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]  %variable  Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter.**

Comment: Try With `For /?`